# Image download in android

Tags: android, imagedownload

I am developing an app where i need to update(replace with another one) my existing images(located in the assets folder) with another image.
How can I download an image into my assets folder?

Comment: `How can I download an image into my assets folder?` You **can't**.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to locate images in Storage and should link your ImageView from url/storage.

If you are developing app with internet *, should not miss picasso library.
[picasso] http://square.github.io/picasso/